# What are the exceptions to consistent event names in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events

What are the Javascript events with different names in different browsers?

I know that the scroll event is different in gecko as DOM-MouseScroll instead of mousewheel, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a reference table, here's one that you may find helpful:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html

I don't know how current it is, but you should still get some good info.

Comment: While that is nice for reference on the standard event types, it doesn't show alternative types when they exist, like with the DOM-MouseScroll event in Gecko.